# How to select an element from drop-down menu using <span>

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I tried the following code below to click drop down:

```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='content']/div/app-appdashboard/div[3]/div/div/div/div/button")).Click();
```

And I tried the following code to click on one of options from drop down:

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='cdk-overlay-0']/div/div/button[16]/span")).Click();

```html
 <button _ngcontent-jco-c9="" aria-haspopup="true" class="btn btn-state dropdown-toggle" mat-button="" ng-reflect-menu="[object Object]">
    <span _ngcontent-jco-c9="" class="ng-star-inserted"> Update Overall App Status </span></button>

    <button _ngcontent-jco-c9="" aria-label="option row button." class="menu-button mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted" mat-menu-item="" role="button" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-role="button" name="PM Supervisor Approved" title="PM Supervisor Approved" aria-disabled="false"><span _ngcontent-jco-c9="">PM Supervisor Approved</span><div class="mat-menu-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div></button>
```

Comment: which span you want to click on? first or second?

Comment: I want to click on first one "Update overall status" to open drop down menu and then click on second button "Pm Supervised Approved" from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
driver.FindElement(By.className("ng-star-inserted")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//button[@name='PM Supervisor Approved']/span")));
driver.FindElement(By.xpath(".//button[@name='PM Supervisor Approved']/span")).click();
```

Comment: : 'invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//button[@name='PM Supervisor Approved')]/span because of the following error:

Comment: is it clicking on first element ?

Comment: made some changes